# Starting PostgreSQL Database

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using

`su -c 'pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l serverlog'` postgres

command to start PostgreSQL 8.0 database. But I am getting "*Permission denied*" error.

Comment: You're joking, version 8.0? You don't want 7 year old software when you can get the latest version for free. It's a waist of time to keep on working with 8.0, move asap to the latest version.

Comment: I don't thing this question belong on StackOverflow, rather ServerFAult or SuperUser ...

Comment: @Frank: 8.0.26 was released two years ago. Plus, you don't know anything about OP:s environment, so don't judge aforehand.

Comment: @bos: It's still 7 years old and also not patched for 2 years. It's EOL, and the OP should have made upgrade plans a long time ago. PostgreSQL gives support for 5 years, after 4 years you know it's time to move on.

Comment: @FrankHeikens "The latest version" isn't necessarily a drop-in upgrade from 8.0. The removal of implicit casts to string, the change to the hex format for bytea, and other breaking changes happened since 8.0. It's important to move to upgrade, but it's not as simple as download; install; done.

Comment: @Frank: You have no idea whether OP is admin or not. OP might not even be *able* to upgrade, so there's really no point in assuming anything that's not stated. Wearing a Judge Dredd-cap is not of any help to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

"Permission denied" is usually a problem with the access rights on the data directory. Make sure the postgres user account has full access to `/usr/local/pgsql/data`

8.0 is completely outdated and de-supported. You should update to the [current version](http://www.postgresql.org/download/) ***now***